# How to do this by looping?

Tags: php

How to do this by for loop ? I wants to set variable according to their existence in array ...

```
if (isset($sort[3])) $c = 3; 
if (isset($sort[4])) $d = 4; 
if (isset($sort[5])) $e = 5; 
if (isset($sort[6])) $f = 6; 
if (isset($sort[7])) $g = 7; 
if (isset($sort[8])) $h = 8; 
if (isset($sort[9])) $i = 9; 
if (isset($sort[10])) $j = 10; 
if (isset($sort[11])) $k = 11; 
if (isset($sort[12])) $l = 12; 
if (isset($sort[13])) $m = 13; 
if (isset($sort[14])) $n = 14; 
if (isset($sort[15])) $o = 15;
```

Comment: Why are you using abcdefg etc. as variable names instead of an array?

Comment: If you need this, you are dong it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, this can actually be accomplished in PHP, since PHP allows you to name variables at runtime using the `$"$<variable_name>"` notation.

```
for ($i = 3; $i <= 15; $i++) {
    if (isset($sort[$i])) {
        $varName = chr(ord ("a") + ($i - 1));
        $$varName = $i
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** In PHP, you can [use strings as variable names](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). To get the right letter of the alphabet, you first compute the right ASCII value using [ord](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php), shift it by `$i - 1`, and then get the character you need by converting the ASCII value to a string using [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php).

While you *can* do this in PHP, I won't necessarily recommend it. It'll be better to have an array/map from the alphabets to the appropriate values.

Comment: what dynamically variables names becomes ?

Comment: They'd be $c through $o, and you can use them henceforth in your code just like you would have used them with your original code. Again, this is **really** bad coding practice, and you'll be better of using a mapping from 'c' through 'o' to the appropriate values (or something similar).